# Edit specific cells of a CSV file using R, without changing anything else

Tags: r, csv, data-manipulation

I want to create a function that changes specific cells of a given CSV file(s) and saves them back into the exact same format.
I have tried to read the CSV file and write it back with the edited values, but the only way to do it without misinterpreting commas is to quote everything.
Is there a way to edit the files without putting quotes for every single value?

My guess is that there is some other way to read and write the CSV files than read.table

p.s. The csv files I want to edit are not in values seperated by columns, but have rather vague format(there may be unquoted, quoted (mostly because of a comma in a string) strings and integers in the same column/row)

Here is the code I use:

```
editcell = function(id,
                    newvalue,
                    row,
                    col,
                    dbpath = "C:/data/",
                    add = FALSE
)
{
        #READ
        temptable = read.table(file = file(paste0(dbpath, id, ".csv")),
                             header = F,
                             sep = ",",
                             dec = ".",
                             fill = TRUE,
                             quote = "",
                             comment.char = "",
                             colClasses = "character",
                             # nrows = 400,
                             stringsAsFactors = F
        );

        cat("There are",nrow(temptable),"rows and",
            ncol(temptable),"columns.");

        #EDIT
        if(add == TRUE) { temptable[x,y] = paste0(temptable[x,y],newvalue)}
        else {temptable[x,y] = newvalue};


        #WRITE
        write.table(temptable,
                    file=paste0(dbpath, id,".csv"),
                    append = F,
                    quote = T,
                    sep=",",
                    eol = "\n",
                    na = "NA",
                    dec = ".",
                    row.names=F,
                    col.names=F,
                    qmethod = "double",
                    fileEncoding = ""
        )

}
```

Comment: `write.table` is useful for writing data in standard formats. If your data is in a "vague" format that doesn't follow the standard definition of CSV, then you won't be able to easily use `write.csv` or `write.table` to read it---and to preserve the nonstandard formatting you probably won't be able to use `read.table` either. You can read the data in as-is with `readLines`, modify it as a string, and output it with `cat`/`sink`. Getting more specific would require a reproducible example and a less "vague" description.

Comment: All the CSVs where created using VBA in excel,. There are every kind of special characters in the CSVs but the problem is with quotes and commas. There are some cells, where the value includes a comma.
These values are quoted, but there may be more than one pair of quotes in a single cell
here is an example of what I meant by vague:
`v2,Arm,,1,"test"\n
""if a= ""Y"", then ""yes"", else ""no""",2,3,4,5`